# Python module imports: import submodules from __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question about python module/submodule structure, imports and best practices.

I've inherited a project structured like this:

```
project
    main_module
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── sub_module_1
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── views.py
    │   └── foo.py
    └── sub_module_2
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── bar.py
        └── views.py
```

In `main_module/__init__.py`, there is some setup code, with imports of some of the sub-modules:

```
from sub_module_1 import foo
...
```

Then `foo.py` imports (for example) sub module 2:

```
import sub_module_2
...
```

So, my questions are:

- When does `__init__.py` run for a given module?
- Will this structure create unexpected circular import problems? None of the sub-modules import `main_module` as a whole (`import main_module`), but I'm not sure if this matters.
- What's the best practice? It seems like lots of set-up with business logic & sub-module imports in `main_module/__init__.py` could complicate things, but it's unclear.

I haven't run into any problems *yet*, but I'm trying to avoid unexpected errors.